Family that is moving into a new house while they are dead, but don't know that
There is a family that is moving into a new house. While driving in a car, it looks like they will lose control of it and crash, but they don't. They arrive to the new house and soon discover ghosts at the new home and lots of other creepy stuff. The plot twist is that they actually died in the car crash and were ghosts, but they don't know it. Later we can see the road where they actually crashed, with their dead bodies in the car.
I know its not:

Beetlejuice
Voices
Dead End

Beside that, the movie didn't look old - I would 2000s, but I'm not sure...

Very similar twist to The Others, but too many other details are different so I doubt it's that.

Haunting of Winchester House is the correct one, thanks"!

You're describing Haunting of Winchester House from 2009.

The film follows Susan (Lira Kellerman) and Drake (Michael Holmes), a couple who has agreed to act as caretakers of a mansion based loosely on the Winchester Mystery House in San Jose, California. Susan and Drake are relentlessly tormented by ghosts who dwell in the house and finally turn to Harrison Dent (Tomas Boykin), a paranormal investigator whom they hope may be able to put the house's ghosts to rest.

When they first drive to the house, they nearly crash their car. In the end, it's revealed that they actually did die in the crash. Here's the trailer:




The plot is very very close to Reeker 2005 

Strangers trapped at an eerie travel oasis in the desert must unravel
  the mystery behind their visions of dying people...




Reeker 2005 Trailer

Is it Wind Chill (2007)? Only one of the characters in that was moving, but many of the themes you describe are in there.


Thanks! but not its not the movie. It was nice warm climate no snow, wind etc..
